# Can maven archetype based projects be updated to latest archetype version later?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

We're having a multi-module based maven project template for custom development we want to reuse. My first intention was to extract everything that's kind of "common" in an maven archetype so whoever may start such a project can just generate it out of a template.

However the template it self (which would be the maven archetype in that scenario) should also be able to evolve as e.g. dependencies it carries update or so on. These changes however shall also be available to "users" of the template afterwards. Is there a mechanism in maven archetype to *update the current to project "to the latest template version"* so the template can be versioned individually? Or how would you solve such a scenario? Just creating a different maven repo with all the templating stuff inside?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Either use a company parent POM, or a BOM (i.e. a list of dependencyManagement in a separate project) to handle this situation.